Using Java annotations, can I use the oneOf annotation to override abstract field to override Swagger documentation creation?
I'm using Swagger UI to create documentation for my Spring Boot API. The result is almost as I want, but the "oneOf" annotation is causing a small problem.
First of all, I've added the springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui as a dependency in my pom.xml file:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

Some of my schema definitions for the Swagger UI are extended from abstract classes. This is where I'm having my problem.
The API is meant to return a list of search results, packed in a pagination object. The search results are abstractly defined as follows (I omitted schema field descriptions, for easier reading):
@Data
public abstract class SearchItemData {
    private String externalId;
    private String type;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, timezone = "Europe/Copenhagen")
    private Date published;
    private String address;
    private String phase;
    private Long estimatedSum;
    private Long buildingArea;
    private String projectStart;
    private String projectEnd;
    private List<RoleData> roles;
}

I have two classes extending SearchItemData:
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
public class ProjectData extends SearchItemData {
    // ...
}

@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
public class ProcurementData extends SearchItemData {
    // ...
}

When getting a result from the endpoint, it's packed in a SearchItemPage object:
@Data
public class SearchItemPage {
    int page;
    int pageCount;
    int pageSize;
    long totalResults;
    // TODO anyOf
    @Schema(
            description = "Array of projects and/or procurements, matching the search parameters",
            oneOf = { ProjectData.class, ProcurementData.class }
    )
    List<SearchItemData> results;
    Long procurementCount;
    Long projectCount;
}

The problem is, when deploying the application, and opening the generated Swagger UI, I get the following:

The schema for ProjectData and ProcurementData are correct, but it seems like inheritance doesn't really go well with the "oneOf" annotation. I can see the logic in how it goes wrong, but I'm having trouble finding a solution.
I've tried defining the list as List<? extends SearchItemData>, which didn't really do anything.
I've seen some people use interfaces instead, which would require some workaround for me, and I'm not really sure it would work here. And I can't find a way to override the automatic scheme definition creation, as I'm lacking some use case examples in the documentation for the library.

You might need to add something like
@Schema(allOf = ParentClass.class)

in the derived classes and
@Schema(subTypes = {DerivedClassA.class, DerivedClassB.class},
    discriminatorProperty = "type",
    discriminatorMapping = {
            @DiscriminatorMapping(value = "typeA", schema = DerivedClassA.class),
            @DiscriminatorMapping(value = "typeB", schema = DerivedClassB.class)
    })

in the parent class.

This helped partially - expanding either project or procurement in the "oneOf" under SearchItemData now only shows the derived fields. Although, that is not entirely what I wanted. I wanted the oneOf to be all the way out under "results".

@JaisBC hmm in the raw openapi spec the ProjectData component should mostly consist of an allOf that has a $ref to the SearchItemData component and then separately list the properties that are not derived-> swagger ui then should visualize that as you want it (assuming I understood the goal correctly^^). Maybe double check whether the spec looks like that.

@JaisBC Aaah, your issue is probably that the schema annotation on the list is applied to the individual items of the list not the list itself. Which makes sense because the full list cannot be "oneOf" of the two subclasses. If you want to move it out, you either need to wrap the list in a class and then have that class do the subtyping, i.e. one class that is a list of ProjectData and one class that is a list of the other derived class. But you loose the attribute sharing then probably. You can also play around with the @ArraySchema annotation instead (that should be applied to the list

rather than the elements). However, if I were you, I would probably go with the current solution as I don't exactly see why you would want to move the oneOf one level up.

Thanks fort the insight, this makes good sense, I might try with @ArraySchema at some point. I'm marking this answer as the solution, since this is what I went with, and your comments made me understand the problem.
